# remember part of string in variable

Tags: regex, perl, scripting, csv

The idea is that I have to read every line of file (CSV) and remember specific information in specific location as variable.
example:

```
a;b;c;d;e;f123;g;h;i;j
```

I know how to read every line but problem is how to save info where the `f123` is and store it in the variable. Any ideas?
Variable should change in every loop (when another line is checked, variable should change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my @list = split ";", $line;
my $value = $list[5];
```

Comment: pure and simple, great :> Thx

Comment: @f00sa `my $value = (split /;/, $line)[5]` But if you can have quoted semi-colons, this will break with input such as: `a;b;c;"Quote: I have *plenty* of common sense; I just choose not to use it.";e;f123;i;j`. Using a CSV module such as Text::CSV is a safer option.

Comment: @f00sa - in case of loop,you can push `$list[5]` in an array.`push @arr,$list[5];` and then you can print this array.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use CPAN module [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-0.87/CSV_XS.pm)

It can utilize any user-specified characters as delimiters, separators, and escapes, it helps to deal with any csv files.